# symfony2 requirements cant be met

Tags: php, apache, symfony, windows-7

Was trying to play with symfony2. If I hit the `web/config.php` of my symfony2 installation it shows me the following problems

```
Install and enable the mbstring extension.
Install and enable the intl extension (used for validators).
Install and enable a PHP accelerator like APC (highly recommended).
Install PDO drivers (mandatory for Doctrine).
```

I can understand that these are not mandatory ones but question is I fixed these in my `php.ini` file but still cant see any reflection in this page. Here is how I fixed the above problems

```
extension=php_intl.dll
extension=php_mbstring.dll
extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
```

Didnt install anything for APC so no complain with that. Restarted apache server "thousand" times, but no luck.

Side Note:

I tried to figure out something from `phpinfo()`. I can see one discrepancy. The phpinfo is showing one of my old php directory path `F:\Softwares\Development\PHP\php-5.5.13-x64`. This path used to exist in my system PATH variable earlier. But I myself remove this location from System PATH variable. But it is still visible in phpinfo(). But if I print the PATH variable from command prompt or cygwin console, it shows the correct PATH variable.

Also ran `php app/check.php`. It shows everything OK except the APC, which is completely fine for me. But it also shows that `"PHP CLI can use a different php.ini file than the one used with your web server"`.

Environment Details:

- **OS:** Windows 7
- **php:** php-5.4.30-Win32-VC9-x86
- **Apache:** Win32-2.4.9 VC9
- **MySQL:** mysql-5.6.19-winx64
- Not using any xampp/wampp etc.

Few more hear left on my head. Please help.

Comment: check apache log if there's no errors while restarting

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have these extensions in your `ext` directory, if not search and put it in the directory (for windows extension file type must be .dll).

- APC https://www.dropbox.com/s/hmnrgle8xing3fo/php_apc.dll
- INTL https://www.dropbox.com/s/wm14zk0grc6pm6v/php_intl.dll (you also need ICU lib)
- mbstring https://www.dropbox.com/s/wm14zk0grc6pm6v/php_intl.dll
- PDO mysql https://www.dropbox.com/s/hd5cm02oti8qw3s/php_pdo_mysql.dll

Also, don't forget to restart apache after changes in php.ini